# Countable family of pairwise disjoint sets of full outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The following question is exercise 134Xi in D. Fremlin's Measure Theory volume 1. It is a "Basic exercise". Usually, basic exercises are basic indeed and not too difficult. I stumble on this one, however.

Recall that a set $A \subset [0,1]$ has full outer measure if any (Lebesgue-)measurable $F \subset [0,1] \setminus A$ is negligible (i.e. the outer Lebesgue measure of $A$ is 1). Prove that there is a disjoint sequence $(A_n)$ of subsets of $[0,1]$, all of full outer measure.

Note that 134D (in the book quoted above) is the statement that there is some subset $C$ of the real line such that both $C$ and and its complement are of full outer measure. Of course we are trying to improve on this. I am not able to modify the proof of 134D in order to achive this, though.

[Also, I am aware of the fact that we can actually find a non-countable family of disjoint subsets of outer measure, but I would like to see an elementary (i.e. "basic") proof of the weaker result above.]

Comment: I don't know what would be appropriate background to use, but you can find the countably infinite case discussed in the last answer (and its comments) in the math overflow question [Is there a maximum to the amount of disjoint non-measurable subsets of the unit interval with full outer measure?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/is-there-a-maximum-to-the-amount-of-disjoint-non-measurable-subsets-of-the-unit).

Comment: Incidentally, I believe the earliest mention in the literature that it is possible to partition $[0,1]$ into countably infinitely many pairwise disjoint sets, each with outer Lebesgue measure $1,$ is pp. 243-244 of Edward B. Van Vleck's 1908 Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. paper [*On non-measurable sets of points, with an example*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1908-009-02/S0002-9947-1908-1500812-5/S0002-9947-1908-1500812-5.pdf).

Comment: Yes I've read that MO thread and comments. According to Gerald Edgar, the Vitali construction may be used to answer the problem but I don't see how. This article of Van Vleck looks interesting but not quite easy to read. Anyway, thank you Mr Renfro.

Comment: I looked some more and found this math overflow question --  [Vitali sets of full outer measure](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120168/vitali-sets-of-full-outer-measure) -- by googling "vitali set" and "full measure" together.

Comment: This construction is not really elementary but maybe Fremlin has higher expectations on his reader than I first thought. I'll try to understand  that. Thank you.

Comment: That was my thought also (that the construction doesn't seem as elementary as one might think from the question), and I tried to think of a way that doesn't go further than what one covers in a *typical* measure theory class (i.e. no ordinals used) but I didn't think of anything. However, I didn't try looking on the internet very hard, and maybe the search terms I used ("vitali set" and "full measure") might lead to something if you look hard enough.

Comment: If noone comes up with anything really elementary I think I'll write an e-mail to Prof. Fremlin. This problem has suggested a related question to me: I think it is clear that we can find a section $A$ for the relation $x-y \in \mathbf{Q}$ in $\mathbf{R} \setminus \mathbf{Q}$ which is invariant under the operation of $\mathbf{Q}^*$ by multiplication. Such a section must clearly be of infinite outer measure (for the restriction of Lebesgue measure to the set of irrationnals) but I see no reason why it should be of full outer measure.

Comment: ...if it were it would be a solution to my question (very similar to Prof Israel's construction I admit). But this new question is interesting itself I think.